# Pyspark: Is there a way to create a Summary table (or dataframe) by merging multiple rows into one?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have created the following dataframe by parsing mulitple CSVs in spark. I need to group the average sales of each month per-city per-SKU per-year.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>city</th><th>sku_id</th><th>year</th><th>month</th><th>avg_sales</th></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>SKU1</td><td>2017</td><td>Jan</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>SKU1</td><td>2017</td><td>Feb</td><td>120</td></tr><tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr><tr><td>Z</td><td>SKU100</td><td>2019</td><td>Dec</td><td>99</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Desired output:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>city</th><th>sku_id</th><th>year</th><th>Jan_avg_sales</th><th>Feb_avg_sales</th><th>..</th><th>Dec_avg_sales</th></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>SKU1</td><td>2017</td><td>100</td><td>120</td><td>..</td><td>320</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>SKU1</td><td>2017</td><td>98</td><td>118</td><td>..</td><td>318</td></tr><tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr><tr><td>Z</td><td>SKU100</td><td>2019</td><td>99</td><td>114</td><td>..</td><td>314</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I have implemented the summary table creation using python dictionary, but i'm not convinced with the solution.

Here is the code snippet i tried so far:
path = "s3a://bucket/city1*"
cleaned_df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load(path)
cleaned_df = cleaned_df.groupby(['Year','city','sku_id']).mean()
cleaned_df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("mydata4csv")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dataframe that looks like:

```
   avg_sales city sku_id  year
0        300    A   sku1  2017
1        210    A   sku1  2018
2        200    A   sku2  2017
3         10    A   sku2  2017
4         10    B   sku1  2017
5        190    B   sku1  2017
6        130    B   sku2  2017
7        130    B   sku2  2017
8         50    C   sku2  2017
```

Then you can do:

```
dataframe.groupby(['year', 'city', 'sku']).mean()
```

And get:

```
                  avg_sales
city sku_id year           
A    sku1   2017        300
            2018        210
     sku2   2017        105
B    sku1   2017        100
     sku2   2017        130
C    sku2   2017         50
```

If you share your python code I can touch up the answer to fit your case.

Comment: path = "s3a://bucket/city1*"
cleaned_df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load(path)
cleaned_df = cleaned_df.groupby(['Year','city','sku_id']).mean()
cleaned_df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("mydata4csv") .  ( here is the code snippet )

Answer (score 1):

did u try to group them based on the three attributes(city, SKU, year)?